# when i click on single list it crashes and gives null pointer exception

Tags: php, android, wampserver

I am creating a hotel directory. when I click on list item of hotels it displays the list, but when i click on single list it crashes and gives null pointer exception in this file in the method doinbackground.

In this file i am trying to get the data of each hotel from the database.i am entering hotel data in one activity it gets saved to databse and shows in the form of list.but wen I click each list item i.e hotel name it should show the details of hotel like location and phone number etc. here is my **EditProductActivity.java** code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

    public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

            EditText txtName;
            EditText txtPhone;
            EditText txtMobile;
            EditText txtDesc;
      EditText txtCreatedAt;
       Button btnSave;
       Button btnDelete;

       String pid;

            // Progress Dialog
       private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            // JSON parser class
       JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            // single product url
       private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/android_hive/get_product_details1.php";

            // url to update product
     private static final String url_update_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_hive/update_product1.php";

            // url to delete product
            private static final String url_delete_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_hive/delete_product1.php";

            // JSON Node names
       private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
       private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
       private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
       private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
       private static final String TAG_PRICE = "phone";
            private static final String TAG_MOBILE = "mobile";
            private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "location";

            @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

                // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

                // getting product details from intent
                Intent i = getIntent();

                // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

                // Getting complete product details in background thread
                new GetProductDetails().execute();

                // save button click event
                btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // starting background task to update product
                        new SaveProductDetails().execute();
                    }
                });

                // Delete button click event
                btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // deleting product in background thread
                        new DeleteProduct().execute();
                    }
                });

            }

            /**
             * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
             * */
            class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading hotel details. Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                /**
                 * Getting product details in background thread
                 * */
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    // updating UI from Background Thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // Check for success tag
                            int success;
                            try {
                                // Building Parameters
                                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                        url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                                // check your log for json response
                                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                                // json success tag
                                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                                if (success == 1) {
                                    // successfully received product details
                                    JSONArray productObj = json
                                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                                    // hotel with this pid found
                                    // Edit Text
                                    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                                    txtPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                                    txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMobile);
                                    txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                                    // display product data in EditText
                                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                                    txtPhone.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                                    txtMobile.setText(product.getString(TAG_MOBILE));
                                    txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                                }else{
                                    // product with pid not found
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    return null;
                }


                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
             * */
            class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                /**
                 * Saving product
                 * */
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                    // getting updated data from EditTexts
                    String name = txtName.getText().toString();
                    String phone = txtPhone.getText().toString();
                    String mobile = txtMobile.getText().toString();
                    String location = txtDesc.getText().toString();

                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, phone));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_MOBILE, mobile));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, location));

                    // sending modified data through http request
                    // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                            "POST", params);

                    // check json success tag
                    try {
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully updated
                            Intent i = getIntent();
                            // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                            setResult(100, i);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // failed to update product
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }


                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            /*****************************************************************
             * Background Async Task to Delete Product
             * */
            class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                /**
                 * Deleting product
                 * */
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // product successfully deleted
                            // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                            Intent i = getIntent();
                            // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                            setResult(100, i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                }

            }
        }
```

I am getting data from php using database and WAMP server. actually this file must show a edit screen where if i want i can make changes or save it or delete it using buttons.
            my php code is:

```
        <?php

        /*
         * Following code will get single product details
         * A product is identified by product id (pid)
         */

        // array for JSON response
        $response = array();

        // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect1.php';

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // check for post data
        if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
            $pid = $_GET['pid'];

            // get a product from products table
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM info WHERE pid = $pid");

            if (!empty($result)) {
                // check for empty result
                if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                    $product = array();
                    $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
                    $product["name"] = $result["name"];
                    $product["phone"] = $result["phone"];
                    $product["mobile"] = $result["mobile"];
                    $product["location"] = $result["location"];
                    $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
                    $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];
                    // success
                    $response["success"] = 1;

                    // user node
                    $response["product"] = array();

                    array_push($response["product"], $product);

                    // echoing JSON response
                    echo json_encode($response);
                } else {
                    // no product found
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "No product found";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            } else {
                // no product found
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "No product found";

                // echo no users JSON
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else {
            // required field is missing
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        ?>
```

this is a php code which is linked to the above java code through url.i am using a json parser as ahelper class to make http connections to datbase and server
            please can anyone help me and tell y my application crashes

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this:

```
txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
txtPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMobile);
txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

 // display product data in EditText
 txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
 txtPhone.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
 txtMobile.setText(product.getString(TAG_MOBILE));
 txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
```

you need to move them to `onPostExecute()` you cant do any UI in `doInBackground`

so it should look like this:

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                 pDialog.dismiss();
   txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
   txtPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
   txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMobile);
  txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

   // display product data in EditText
   txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
   txtPhone.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
   txtMobile.setText(product.getString(TAG_MOBILE));
   txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
}
```

you may need to consider putting `JSONObject product` as global variable so it can be accessed in both `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`.

hope you got the idea. give me a feedback if it worked

Comment: He is using runOnUiThread, he is setting on the UI thread. IMO the problem lays somewhere else.